# How can I specify a float value for a test with this output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

```
describe('convert', () => {
  test
  .stdout()
  .command(['convert'])
  .it('runs convert', ctx => {
    expect(ctx.stdout).to.equal()
  })

  test
  .stdout()
  .command(['convert', '--amount', '50', '--from', 'EUR', '--to', 'USD'])
  .it('convert  --amount 50 --from EUR --to USD', ctx => {
    expect(ctx.stdout).to.contain('')
  })
})
```

Exit for function:

Example: 1.2345

I need to know how to make the test check the output knowing that the value is a float.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used      `expect(typeof ctx.stdout === typeof 1.0)`
for the kind of response I was expecting.
The code has been like this:

```
describe('convert', () => {
  test
  .stdout()
  .command(['convert'])
  .it('runs convert', ctx => {
    expect(typeof ctx.stdout === typeof 1.0)
  })

  test
  .stdout()
  .command(['convert', '--amount', '50', '--from', 'EUR', '--to', 'USD'])
  .it('convert  --amount 50 --from EUR --to USD', ctx => {
    expect(typeof ctx.stdout === typeof 1.0)
  })
})
```